# Was Palpatine involved in setting up Ahsoka?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious

In season 5 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, when the Jedi Temple was bombed (which put the Jedi Order in suspect only to damage their reputation) I thought Palpatine was behind this.

All militaristic setup to lure Ahsoka in the trap made my belief more powerful.

But, in the season finale, it was shown that another Jedi was behind this and the trap against Ahsoka didn't look official after that. It looked possible for a Jedi to setup such things (putting key card in front of Ahsoka, killing clones with Ahsoka's lightsaber etc).

But, I still suspect about Palpatine's involvement. Is there a solid clue to say Palpatine was involved in this from any level?

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is no, Palpatine has not been established to have had any direct influence in the bombing of the Jedi Temple. However, as Pasteur said, "Chance favors the prepared mind," and Palpatine has certainly set up circumstances so that such an event could occur.

He has kept the Clone Wars dragging on for several years, turning the opinion of the public against the heavily-involved Jedi. By having the Jedi fight in the war, he created a moral dilemma for those in the Order, who thought of themselves as peacekeepers. He placed people like Tarkin in the military, who advocated against the Jedi.

It's worth noting, however, that Barriss Offee's motivations are covered only briefly, but she says that the Jedi are serving the Dark Side by fighting in the war. This leads me to question what she knows, or at least what she thinks she knows. Did she find out that Palpatine was a Sith? Does she only suspect that Jedi are being manipulated by some unidentified Sith? Could Palpatine have tricked her in some way? Or is it just that she feels that any fighting at all is serving the Dark Side?

While this is entirely speculation, it seems possible that Palpatine could have had some direct influence on her, especially given his ability to manipulate people.