# What happened to Ahsoka Tano after she left the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the last episode of the Clone Wars cartoon series, Ahsoka Tano was accused by the Jedi Council and put out of the Order, but after some diligent research, Anakin found out who was the [real culprit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32517/was-palpatine-involved-in-setting-up-ahsoka?rq=1), so Ahsoka's name was cleared.

The Jedi Order asked her to return, but she declined their offer.

So, uh, what happened to her after that? [Wookieepedia does not say](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano).

**NOTE**

I asked this question before *Rebels* even came out, back when there was really no information to be had save for some hearsay. There is so much information now about Ahsoka that there's no reason to ask a question like this any more.

So, when you read this, please keep in mind that the question is dated.

Comment: And there you have your answer... An author may take up Ashoka and write about her after the events of the cartoon. As of now it is not known!

Comment: It is not canon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plot was just to make the TV series compatible with the movies. What happened to Ashoka Tano after the TV plot has never been mentioned in the canon.

As next season of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* has been [cancelled by Disney](https://www.wired.com/underwire/2013/03/disney-clone-wars-cancelled/) (after it purchased LucasFilm), all chances of getting to know about ultimate fate have gone to void. "What happened to Darth Maul?" is troubling me more than this..

**Update:**
The later released *Unfinished season 6 (The Lost Missions)* of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* showed nothing about Ahsoka, but we now know what happened to her, thanks to *Star Wars: Rebels* TV series:

> S01E13 of *Star Wars: Rebels* revealed that Ahsoka survived Order 66 and she was a member of Rebel Alliance.

Comment: Actually, there is a chance we will find out. [The episodes that Disney cancelled were already in production and will be released next year](http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2013/10/12/final-episodes-of-star-wars-the-clone-wars-to-arrive-next-year/)

Comment: Just finished watching Season 6 and unfortunately Ahsoka Tano did not return in this season.

Comment: @TolandH: More precisely, she did, but only for a moment, and only in a vision.

Comment: The problem is Maul is still unknown to us considering the Books out their.  My guess is Maul knows when to play, and when just leave the son and grandsons of Anakin Skywalker alone!  Sith love glory and all, but getting your ass handed to you a third time doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Thanks to the finale of Rebels, we can now say that Ahsoka survives the entire war and then runs off with Sabine to look for Esra. Sure to be continued in a comic or webseries, if not another animated show.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Clone Wars Adventures Character Wiki](https://cwcharacter.fandom.com), Ahsoka marries a Jedi named Kol Kerz-Tak who, according to his bio, was a pretty big deal to the Jedi order (even though he is never introduced or even mentioned in any of the movies). But before they got married Ahsoka joined forces with Kol and Assada Zadira and survived Order 66. Later on she (Ahsoka) became a member of the Jedi high counsel in the new Jedi order and Kol became a grand Jedi master alongside Luke Skywalker.

I don't know who made the website or its credibility in accordance with Lucasfilm, but that is all I have found concerning Ahsoka Tano after the end of the Clone Wars series.

Comment: These are non-canonical fan stories as stated by the [author](http://cwacharacter.wikia.com/wiki/User:Malek_Kriya) several times on [Kol Kerz-Tak page](http://cwacharacter.wikia.com/wiki/Kol_Kerz-Tak). The wiki is based on [Clone Wars Adventure](http://starwars.com/play/online-games/clone-wars-adventures/) video game.

Answer (score 2):

*Star Wars: Rebels*,  is [on its way - autumn 2014](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels):

Also there are some now completed episodes from the cancelled season 6 of SW:CW on their way:

> "On October 11, 2013, Filoni announced that his crew had completed production on the remaining The Clone Wars episodes and that they will be released in early 2014. The venue through which they will be released has yet to be specified.[5]"
>   [Season 6 announcement](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Clone_Wars:_Season_Six)

Ahsoka's such a popular character that it wouldn't surprise me to see her in one or other of these.

Answer (score 1):

In Star Wars The Clone Wars: Legacy (the unfinished Season 7) in episode 2, Anakin and Obi Wan discuss Ashoka's choice to leave the order, but no more details are given, and that's the last mention of Ashoka in the cartoons before Rebels.

In Star Wars Rebels, Season 1, Episode 13, Ashoka Tano makes her first appearance as she rescues the small rebel group from pursuing Star Destroyers.  She is part of `Fulcrum` - a pre-rebel alliance group with ties to Bail Organa.

Also in this episode is the first appearance of Darth Vader!

However, this episode doesn't tell where she's been all this time and how she escaped Order 66.  Hopefully this story will be told!

Comment: Obviously she escaped 66 because she was no longer a jedi. Duh

Comment: She was still a Jedi - she had all her Jedi powers, and was really invalidly "expelled".  I am sure that when Order 66 went out that if any stormtroopers saw her they would have killed her.

Comment: @BGM: She was offered her place as a Jedi back. But she had been expelled and was no longer part of the Jedi Order. Of course that doesn't erase her skills and abilities, but it does technically mean she isn't a Jedi. Just like Dark Jedi aren't technically Sith. Just using the Force and a lightsaber does not make one Jedi or Sith, although the average Twi'lek on the street won't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Ahsoka's Untold Stories. They explain everything that happened up to *Revenge of the Sith*. They are canon in the eyes of Pablo Hidalgo, who is in charge of canon. A book is being released in 2016, called *Ahsoka*. That is supposed to explain everything as well.

Comment: Yeah, I asked this question before Rebels even came out.  Now there's plenty of info and no reason to ask a question like this anymore.  Thanks though!